# Nested view model in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Still trying to learn MVVM and WPF here.

I'm trying to create a complex view model `EditArticleViewModel`. It has some code that is repeated for similar controls and so I've moved the repeating code into another class. Then, I've added several instances of that other class into `EditArticleViewModel`.

I will set an instance of `EditArticleViewModel` as my window's `DataContext`. And I will bind to things like `Categories.Items` and `Subcategories.SelectedItem`.

```
public class CategoryView
{
    public ObservableCollection<object> Items { /* */ }
    public object SelectedItem { /* ... */ }
}

public class SubcategoryView
{
    public ObservableCollection<object> Items { /* */ }
    public object SelectedItem { /* ... */ }
}

public class EditArticleViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public CategoryView Categories { get; private set; }
    public SubcategoryView Subcategories { get; private set; }

    public EditArticleViewModel()
    {
        Categories = new CategoryView();
        SubcategoryView Subcategories new SubcategoryView();
    }

    // Additional properties and methods here

}
```

As you can see, my `EditArticleViewModel` class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` so that I can notify the visual elements when something has changed.

My question is about how I notify visual elements about changes within `CategoryView` and `SubcategoryView`. Is there a way to notify the window about changes within these classes directly? Or must I raise an event from each class and have `EditArticleViewModel` handle that event in order to send the appropriate notification?

Any tips appreciated.

Comment: Could you have `SubcategoryView` and `CategoryView` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`and just let the view handle the changes?

Comment: @Michael: But then wouldn't I need to set the `DataContext` to these class instances?

Comment: @JonathanWood If the Binding can find a given property on a given object, don't you think it can also find the object that it found the property on? Quit borrowing trouble and write some trivial code to play with this stuff. You'll have plenty of real questions soon enough.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: Say what? It can find the object just fine. My question was about propagating notifications. This must be common thing, I'm trying to learn how people are handling it. If your goal is to criticize and not help, please don't respond to my questions.

Comment: @JonathanWood the. Object. Which. Owns. The. Property. Is. What. It. Gets. The. Notification. FROM. Unless you screw up and neglect to implement INotifyPropertyChanged properly. Why propagate notifications? Why add unnecessary complexity?

Comment: @EdPlunkett: It should be clear from the nature of the question that I'm trying to avoid unnecessary complexity. If the object that owns the property gets the notification, then in the case of `Categories.SelectedItem`, `Categories` gets the notification. What I don't understand is how that notification should propagate from `Categories` to `EditArticleView `.

Comment: @JonathanWood if EditArticleView cares, it subscribes to this.Categories.PropertyChanged. By the way you seem to be calling your viewmodels "views"

Comment: @EdPlunkett: Well, since `EditArticleView` is the `DataContext`, wouldn't the notification need to come from this class?

Comment: @JonathanWood Consider this example: `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Categories.SelectedCategory.Name}" />`. The DataContext of the TextBlock is the default Source for the Binding. It looks at the Binding's Source for Categories. So, finding that, it looks on DataContext.Categories for SelectedCategory. It then looks on SelectedCategory for Name, and it subscribes to SelectedCategory.PropertyChanged to listen for changes to Name. I kid you not, try it and see. The DataContext is just the default for Binding.Source.

Comment: The beauty of this is that all the vms can be loosely coupled to each other; each does its own notifications, so a vm that's a child in one context needn't be dependent on that parent, or any parent at all. WPF is all about mixing and matching as freely as possible.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: Okay, so you're saying it will _listen_ to the immediate parent of the source, and not `DataContext` as I guess I was suspecting. If so, that would definitely be cool and flexible. I've been trying to put together code to test this but, unfortunately, my first view model is complicated and probably not the best one for someone learning this stuff. Thanks.

Comment: @JonathanWood Er, to the immediate parent of the property -- at the other end of the Path from the Source. I'd encourage you to make some trivial toy thing to play with this stuff before you try to design something nontrivial with it. It'll save you a lot of time.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: You said in the case of `Categories.SelectedCategory.Name`, it would subscribe to `SelectedCategory.PropertyChanged`. In this case, I'm considering `Name` to be the actual source and `SelectedCategory` to be the immediate parent of the source. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: By "Source" I'm talking about the Source property of the Binding object created by the {Binding ...} thing in the XAML. I could have specified the Source for it (you rarely do, but you can); since I didn't, it defaulted to the current data context -- which will be that of the TextBox whose text property I put the binding on. All Binding.Source is, is the object where it looks for the property identified by Binding.Path. The Path is the unnamed default property: My binding was shorthand for `{Binding Path=Categories.SelectedItem.Name}`.

Comment: There's (unfortunately) another usage of the word "source" which applies to Name: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger(v=vs.110).aspx -- where "source" is the thing being updated, which is the Name property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should only be one ViewModel per View, with an extend that primary ViewModel can contain other "ViewModels".

So when you set `DataContext` to your primary ViewModel **all the content** of it will be have a subscription to `NotifyPropertyChanged` event, thus implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in other derived ViewModel will be notified.

I would suggest implementing a base class with `INotifyPropertyChanged` `interface` which you could derive from in your other ViewModels.

By having this alteration you should solve the problem you are having:

```
public class ObservableViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propName = null)
    {
         PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}

public class CategoryView : ObservableViewModelBase
{
  public ObservableCollection<object> Items { /* */ }
  public object SelectedItem { /* ... */ }
}

public class SubcategoryView : ObservableViewModelBase
{
  public ObservableCollection<object> Items { /* */ }
  public object SelectedItem { /* ... */ }
}

public class EditArticleView : ObservableViewModelBase
{
  public CategoryView Categories { get; set; } = new CategoryView();
  public SubcategoryView Subcategories { get; set; } = new SubcategoryView();
}
```

Regarding `ObservableCollection`. It will notify view to change only when you add/remove items but it does not notify when content is changed. To update view on item content change you should have something like that:

```
public class GridRowItemViewModel : ObservableViewModelBase // From previous example.
{
      private string _sampleProp;          
      public string SampleProp
      {
          get
          {
              return _sampleProp;
          }
          set
          {
              _sampleProp = value;
              OnPropertyChanged();
          }
      }
}
```

And thus your Main ViewModel should look something like this:

```
public class MainViewModel : ObservableViewModelBase // This is your DataContext.
{
     public ObservableCollection<GridRowItemViewModel> GridCollection { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT:** You cannot bind to fields, WPF does not resolve fields. It can only handle properties. So by creating plain fields of child ViewModels you are getting no where. Change these into properties and you will be able to access its content in the View by the property name.

Comment: I'm not quite understanding this. So implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` in my child classes is trivial enough. But I'm trying to understand how those notifications propagate to the parent `EditArticleView` class. I don't see the answer to that in your code.

Comment: If you want to notify about changes within your child ViewModels you should implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface within these child ViewModels. View will see the implementation and subscribe to the NotifyPropertyChanged event.